# Make lift go up?

Tags: c#

So I found this lift script online, and the answer is probably so obvious and I feel stupid for not seeing this earlier, but right now this script makes the lift go down, how do I make it go up? I've tried rearranging the transform.positions in different x,y,z combinations but no luck. Thoughts?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Elevator3 : MonoBehaviour {

    public int speed = 1;
    private int i = 10;
    bool keyPressed = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            keyPressed = true;
        }

        if (keyPressed == true)
        {
            startLift();
        }
    }

    void startLift()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, 
            new Vector3(transform.position.x, 10, transform.position.z),
            Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    void stopLift()
    {
        keyPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "So I found this lift script online" so go back there to investigate, provide some link to that, attribute your source.  Seems like the answer is in the `Vector3.Lerp` code which is not supplied

Comment: As if I wasn't scared enough of lifts!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about Unity but anyway... assuming Cartesian coordinates, have you tried increasing the 'y' coordinate in StartLift? Maybe something like

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, 
        new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+10, transform.position.z),
        Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

I quite like the thought you could also change the x and z coordinates and make the world's first 3 dimensional lift.

Comment: Your transform.position.y+10 suggestion worked! I understand your feelings on the situation, but I can assure you that wasn't my intention. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @MadDog_Gaming No worries. Glad you got sorted. If my answer worked could you upvote it please. Thanks.